# Drake geometry_inspector.py: error: File does not exist:

Tags: ubuntu, drake

I have ubuntu 20.04.
When I try run example

```
./bazel-bin/manipulation/util/geometry_inspector \ ./manipulation/models/iiwa_description/sdf/iiwa14_no_collision.sdf
```

I have got error:

```
usage: geometry_inspector.py [-h] [--find_resource] [--package_path PACKAGE_PATH] [--meshcat [zmq_url]] [--open_browser]
                             [--meshcat_role {illustration,proximity}] [--meshcat_hydroelastic] [--pyplot] [--visualize_collisions]
                             [--position POSITION [POSITION ...] | --joint_position JOINT_POSITION [JOINT_POSITION ...]] [--test]
                             filename
geometry_inspector.py: error: File does not exist: /home/dmitriy/git/drake/ ./manipulation/models/iiwa_description/sdf/iiwa14_no_collision.sdf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found mistake, I had to run this commands in separate lines.